# how to get something like: "ℓ1-Norm"

Tags: symbols

It's very common to use `L_{1}` as norm symbol. But it
doesn't look like as nice as "ℓ 1". I'm wondering how
can I get "ℓ1" using Latex.

Comment: try `\ell`. i wonder if this is a duplicate of another question...

Comment: @cmhughes: Sure appears to be...

Comment: You should be aware that $\ell^1$ and $L^1$ are usually meant to be different spaces.